# Level Generation Not Working in Python and I don't know why

Tags: python

I wrote a script to generate a level in Python. For some reason, it did each row vertically and not horizontally.

My Code:

```
level = '''
   g
  ggg
gggggggggggggggg'''
x=0
y=0
for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == 'g':
            plats.append(ground.Ground(x,y,50,WINDOW))

        x += 50
    y += 50
    x = 0
```

Comment: `for row in level` I don't think this is doing what you expect.  `level` is a string, and when you iterate over a string, you get _each individual character_.  It does NOT return a whole row at once.

Comment: I changed it to a list with each row as a string and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`level` here is a one-dimensional string with newlines. Python will, by default, treat the newlnes like any other character while iterating over the string. If you want to process each line as a row, then there are two approaches you can take. First would be to rewrite `level` as a list of strings:

```
level = [
    '   g',
    '  ggg',
    'gggggggggggggggg',
[
```

or second, keep `level` defined as before, but instead of having your first look iterate over the entire string, have it split the string on newlines:

```
for row in level.split('\n'):
```